# .NET Standard Library && Framework Project: "Could Not Get Dependencies for Project Reference "

Tags: .net-standard

I have a Solution that has 15 libraries (13 .NET Standard 2.0.2 and 2 Framework 4.7.1) and 7 web projects using Framework 4.7.1

The 2 libraries using Framework 4.7.1 all is working as expected with references and finding dependencies (they are encapsulated all unto their own so do not require any dependency on any .NET Standard library)

To fix the issue, I have tried:

1. isolating a library to where it does not require any dependency on another .net library (still generates issue)
2. Adding

   ```
   <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects> <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>   <RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</RestoreProjectStyle>
   ```

I cannot seem to resolve error, any suggestions?

Thanks in advance and for all replies

Comment: It is the kind of error you get when the projects have incompatible framework targets.  Should not happen for .netstandard projects, ensure that one of them is not accidentally a .netcore project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What helped resolve the issue in my case was I created a new Web Application with Empty template and moved files/references/dependencies/web.config/etc. and rebuilt the solution.

From my estimation, the issue was might have been that it was the classic web site as that version has limited MSBuild support.